# Does Delphi and FPC have MakeWord functions (out of two bytes or chars)?

Tags: delphi, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, cpu-word, freepascal

These functions are useful:

```
function MakeWord(low, high: char): word;
begin
  result := byte(high) shl 8 + byte(low);
end; 

function MakeWord(low, high: byte): word;
begin
  result := high shl 8 + low;
end;
```

However I am wondering if these kinds of functions (could be implemented differently) already exist somewhere (not in a windows api specific file, but rather a cross platform RTL function).

Example use case: take the two characters GT and make a WORD result out of it.

```
MakeWord('G','T');
```

I find this more readable than inserting SHL/SHR AND/OR hex operations and other hacks in the code that do not describe what the code is doing... so surely these functions exist somewhere already? Or do people roll their own in their applications?

Or something like:

```
var x: word;
begin
  lo(x) := byte('G');
  hi(x) := byte('T');
end;
```

However, that will not work as the left side cannot be assigned to: but it is more readable, than some other solutions, IMO.

I think I have seen LoWord and HiWord functions too (or LoByte, HiByte) but usually in read only cases. What about writing to the hi and lo?

Comment: Are you aware about size of `Char`?

Comment: @MBo: I guess that the cast to `Byte()` solves that.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis This cast hides potential problem (information loss), not solves it fully

Comment: @MBo: on a big-endian platform, it would be a problem, indeed.

Comment: MBo, what would be solving it fully? Thanks for the note. Also, in Remy's answer he uses Ord() and Byte() (two casts) ...  These are the sorts of nasty things I wish programming languages could avoid. Indeed the use of a cast is the first warning something may not be right. On a wiki, someone once said the cast is the start of a lie.

Comment: This is because `Char` type is misleading and simply wrong. It isn't standard C's byte, it's Windows' `TCHAR`.

Comment: except, AFAIR, freepascal's char *is* a C style char, unless fpc has changed it recently to something else. Delphi's char, on the other hand, is not guaranteed to be a 1 byte C style char. IMO life would be easier if char was char like it used to be, the good old days, but that will never happen with Unicode and all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi and FreePascal both have a `WordRec` record in the `SysUtils` unit:

Delphi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.WordRec

FreePascal: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/wordrec.html

For example:

```
uses
 ..., SysUtils;

var
  x: Word;
begin
  WordRec(x).Lo := Byte(Ord('G'));
  WordRec(x).Hi := Byte(Ord('T'));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer: Just a note: do you need to cast it twice, using ord and byte, or just use byte() cast, and skip the ord altogether?

Comment: @OverflowingHuman that depends on the compiler. Since characters are 2-byte `WideChar` in Delphi 2009+, you usually need `Ord` to work with them as ordinal values. The extra `Byte` cast is just more explicit about what is being assigned. Makes the code more self-documenting and avoids any ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FreePascal has makeword in the windows unit.(makeword is originally a winapi macro IIRC)

In addition it also has inline to optimize away call overhead for small functions like this.

Comment: Delphi has the same.

Comment: Yes, but it is a **Windows** macro, in a **Windows** unit. The question specifically asked for a **cross-platform** solution.

Comment: I missed that. The crossplatformness is highly application specific if you count bigendian targets.

Comment: couldn't the cross platform function have ifdef's for all platforms... I suspect maybe the sysutils WordRec may have this implemented (see Remy's answer)?

Comment: makeword itself is not endian sensitive but its usage might be.